# temp. power post requirement for buried sevice fro power co

Tags: electrical

I am trying to set up a temporary power post or pole and meter box.The survive  from the power co.is buried from the transformer.

Comment: You could ask the power company what they recommend.

Comment: It would also be very helpful to [edit] your question to correct all the typos. I'd guess you typed on your phone and the "autocowrecks" didn't help much...

Comment: What your power company requires will be specific to your power company. They will have a requirement, and what anybody else's power company might want is not what matters to you.